# Do I need to take the Hermitian myself when using numpy's outer product function?

Tags: python, numpy, math, vector, physics

Comparing [how outer products normally work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Definition) (***u*** outer ***v*** = ***u***(***v***<sup>+</sup>) = ***u***(***v***<sup>T</sup>)*) and [how it is done in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html), I think I need to supply the Hermitian conjugate to the second argument `b` with `b.conj()`, because the example in numpy's documentation does not show any conjugation. Is my understanding correct? i.e. for two numpy ndarrays `a` and `b`, the outer product should be performed by `numpy.outer(a, b.conj())`.

Comment: You could always test it with a simple example. But anyways, there is no need; as you can see in both links you provided, the (i,j) element of the outer product is just u_i * v_j. The conjugate is taken to follow matrix multiplication rules, which NumPy kind of ignores. Note that you can achieve the same result using broadcasting: `u[:,None] * v`

Comment: `np.matrix` objects have a `.H` property, which is `the (complex) conjugate transpose`.  I think `H` stands for Hermitian.  `np.vdot` applies the `conj`, but only for 1d arrays.  Otherwise you need to use `conj` explicitly if  you need it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `transpose` only changes existing axes.  Thus it does not change 1d arrays.  `outer` expects 1d arrays (or flattens them), so there's no point to applying a transpose to its arguments.  But by taking advantage of broadcasting you can perform 'outer' (and more complex combinations) with element-wise multiplication.